# Is it possible to combine 2 different configurable products for color swatch

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have two configurable products (with sizes) and different colors. Can I combine them in a color swatch, so it switch to the other color?

Or is the best way to make one configurable product with different colors in it?

I can’t find a good (the best) solution for it.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, I didn't quite understand what you meant but, if you have a product with sizes and color create it like the ones in sample data from magento, you enter the product and select size and color

Comment: Yes, understand. But my products are already online and running. Can i combine them?

Comment: I don't think you can, you might have to create all products again, do them disabled then switch after so you have only one active. You can try to create a configurable and add the ones you already have, but I couldn't make it work.